# Select statements using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management 2016

I'm trying to figure out how many players were deceased had a final game before 1/1/1900, and the thing is I don't know if I have the code right because its coming back with nothing.

```
SELECT deathDate, finalGameDate FROM Players 
WHERE deathDate IS NOT NULL AND deathDate = '1990/01/01' and finalGameDate IS NOT NULL
```

[image: Data]

I'm also trying to figure out who tends to weigh more, domestic born or foreign born players and here's a little of the data tables for that as well, I've tried to make the statement and I can't figure it out I keep getting errors left and right; here's the basic select I start from. I've tried Functions and that's where I get my errors.

```
SELECT weight, birthCountry FROM Players where birthCountry is not null 
and weight is not null
```

[image: Country Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For Question 1

Try:

```
 SELECT deathDate, finalGameDate FROM Players
   WHERE Convert(datetime,finalGameDate) <= '1990/01/01'
   AND deathDate Is Not NULL
```

### For Question 2

Try:

```
  SELECT 
        weight, birthCountry,
        case When birthCountry = 'USA' then 'Domestic-Born'
             Else 'Foreign-Born'
        End as [Born]
  FROM Players Order by weight desc
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, first one worked like a carm needed to fix one thing in it though, now the second not so much, I'm trying to trying to figure out who tends to weigh more, domestic born being usa or foreign born players being the rest

Comment: OK thank you for helping, hopefully this can be done as well with that statement that you created. Is there a way to separate foreign and Domestic into separate columns and count to see witch one had the most in players that weight more

Comment: You canuse count for that:


`With CTE as (SELECT 
        weight, birthCountry,
        case When birthCountry = 'USA' then 'Domestic-Born'
             Else 'Foreign-Born'
        End as [Born]
  FROM Players Order by weight desc)

Select  Born,count(Weight) [Count] From CTE Group by weight,Born`

Comment: use 'deathDate is not null' instead of deathDate <> NULL

Comment: How do i do a count for Domestic and Foreign with this SelectStatement SELECT weight, CASE WHEN birthCountry = 'USA' THEN 'Domestic-Born' ELSE 'Foreign-Born' END AS Countries
FROM Players WHERE weight IS NOT NULL

Comment: @CJ87 Add that SELECT statement in cte and apply COUNT on `wieght` GROUP BY `Countries`

Comment: so @KinchitDalwani like this With CTE as (SELECT weight, CASE WHEN birthCountry = 'USA' THEN 'Domestic-Born' ELSE 'Foreign-Born' END AS Countries 
FROM Players WHERE weight IS NOT NULL) Select count(Weight) Countries From CTE Group by Countries and when i run this select it comes back with two rows instead of the rows how would i have it come out in two colums with the names of Domestic and the other Foreign

Comment: Specify the desired output!

Comment: tnx @KinchitDalwani this is what i came up with. WITH CTE AS (SELECT weight, CASE WHEN birthCountry = 'USA' THEN 'Domestic' ELSE 'Foreign' END AS Countries 
FROM Players WHERE weight IS NOT NULL) SELECT count(weight) AS Weigh, Countries AS Countries FROM CTE AS CTE_1 GROUP BY Countries.   Is there another way to make this more simpler and less code ?